# How to get my two divs on the same line without setting a width to each of them?

Tags: html, css

Is this how I should get the divs inline or is there a semantic way it has to be done? When I set the divs to inline and float left only they do not move inline they stay as block can anyone also explain this for me thanks in advance. The reason i have package as the container of the other two divs was to make it inline and hopefully get the other two inline but it didnt work.

**Current Code:**

```css
.packages {} .basic {
  width: 460px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.advanced {
  width: 460px;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">
  <div class="basic">
    <h3>Basic Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit.</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced">
    <h3>Advanced Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `width` set `calc(50% - 20px)`. This `20px` is because margins. By this way, You can keep Your margins.

There is example :

```css
.packages {} .basic {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.advanced {
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="packages">
  <div class="basic">
    <h3>Basic Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit.</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced">
    <h3>Advanced Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use width to 50% and remove margin...if you want gap use padding.

```css
 .packages {
 
 } 

.basic {
   width:50%;
   float: left;
   
 }
 .advanced {
   
   width:50%;
   float: left;
   
 }
```

```html
<div class="packages">
  <div class="basic">
    <h3>Basic Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit.</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="advanced">
    <h3>Advanced Package</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, usu dicit vituperata eu. Doctus utroque efficiendi vis id, cum dicunt possim officiis cu. At quod vidisse nam. Mentitum posidonium ex pro, ad blandit</p>
    <p><a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work for screens that are `960px` or wider (the combined width and margins of each box). Consider using percents if you want to work at all screen sizes.

```
.basic,
.advanced {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

If browser support isn't an issue, you could use [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```
.package {
  display: flex;
}

.basic,
.advanced {
  flex: 1;
}
```

You might also look into frameworks such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that handle all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin` and add width in `%`
Use this css it will help you..

**CSS**

```
.basic {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
 .advanced {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.basic {
display:inline;
float:left;
margin:10px 10px 0px 10px;
max-width:40%;
}

.advanced {
display:inline;
float:right;
margin:10px 10px 0px 10px;
max-width:40%;
}
```

If you are looking for the semantic inline element use a span element  instead than a div

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is already working. If you put your code in a container bigger than 920px, it should stay side by side. But if you want them to stay side by side at anywhere, I recommend you to use percent width as follow.

And it is better to use display:inline-block instead of float:left and display:inline otherwise your two floated divs will be out of main div.packages.

```
.packages {} .basic {
      width: 45%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
    .advanced {
      width: 45%;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    }
```